# Connect to another container using Docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to use two containers together: one with Tomcat and another with a Database.

I have created the following yaml file which describes the services:

```
postgredb:
  image: postgres
  expose:
    - 5432
  ports:
    - 5432:5432
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_USER=user
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
tomcat:
  image:  tomcat
  links:
    - postgredb:db
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
```

After starting docker-compose I can see that I'm not able to reach the Database from Tomcat, unless I retrieve the IP address of the Database (via docker inspect) and use it when configuring Tomcat Connection Pool to the DB.

From my understanding, the two containers should be linked and I'd expect to find the database on localhost at port 5432, otherwise I see little benefits in linking the containers.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use the alias "db" that you have defined in file to refer to the database host name.

> Containers for the linked service will be reachable at a hostname
>   identical to the alias, or the service name if no alias was specified.

Source: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links

Comment: What is the source of this quote?

Comment: @rage it looks like the source is https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links, with a few words modified

Comment: to make this a little clearer: if you have something written like 
base_url_api = "http://127.0.0.1:4999/"
and you have a service called "api", then you can write 
base_url_api = "http://api:4999/"
you actually dont even need to involve network: alias:

Answer (score 3):

For newer versions of docker-compose

> Links are a legacy option. We recommend using networks instead.

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    image: "nginx:alpine"
    networks:
      - new

  worker:
    image: "my-worker-image:latest"
    networks:
      - legacy

  db:
    image: postgredb
    networks:
      new:
        aliases:
          - db
      legacy:
        aliases:
          - postgredb

networks:
  new:
  legacy:
```