# Upload of files into Fake GCS bucket from fsouza in docker not working and need to access this image using my ip address

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, google-cloud-storage

In my node application, when I tried to use fake GCS bucket image from https://github.com/fsouza/fake-gcs-server. I have to use fake gcs bucket because we dont have access to our project GCS bucket publicly even with key. I faced couple of issues.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.9'

networks:
  storage-network:
    driver: bridge
  db-network:
    driver: bridge
  frontend-network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  api:
    container_name: node_api
    build: 
      context: ../node-app/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    ports:
    - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
        - postgres
    restart: on-failure
    volumes:
      - ../node-app/:/app/
    networks:
      - storage-network
    environment:
      # Port
      PORT: 8080

  storage:
    container_name: fake-gcs-server
    image: fsouza/fake-gcs-server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    volumes:
      - ./gcs_bucket:/data
    command: ["-scheme", "http", "-port", "8083", "-external-url", "http://[::]:8083", "-backend", "memory"]
    networks:
      - storage-network
```

NodeJs function to upload file in this GCS bucket.

```
exports.testupload = async (req, res) => {
    const bucketName = 'testBucket';
    try {
        await processFile(req, res);
        const storage = new Storage({
            apiEndpoint: "http://<ip_address_like_192.168..>:8083",
            projectId: "test",
        });

        const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
      
        const blob = bucket.file(req.file.originalname);
        const blobStream = blob.createWriteStream({
            resumable: false,
        });
    
        blobStream.on("error", (err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: err.message });
        });
    
        blobStream.on("finish", async (data) => {
        
            res.status(200).send({
                message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
                url: publicUrl,
            });
        });
    
        blobStream.end(req.file.buffer);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    
        if (err.code == "LIMIT_FILE_SIZE") {
            return res.status(500).send({
                message: "File size cannot be larger than 2MB!",
            });
        }
    
        res.status(500).send({
            message: `Could not upload the file: ${req.file.originalname}. ${err}`,
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the code and check. I always get http code 200 i.e. success. But when I look at mapped folder gcs_bucket I see there is no file in it.

Log in console from docker image of fake_gcs_server:

```
fake-gcs-server  | time="2022-03-12T11:38:42Z" level=info msg="192.168.80.1 - - [12/Mar/2022:11:38:42 +0000] \"POST /upload/storage/v1/b/testbucket/o?uploadType=multipart&name=test_1647085120709.txt HTTP/1.1\" 200 476"
```

In another similar example I am able to read file from this fake GCS bucket. But I am facing below two problems.

1. Uploading of document into mapped gcs_bucket/testBucket directory not working.
2. In apiEndpoint, instead of localhost, I need to mention my ipv4 ipaddress starting 192.168.

Please let me know where I am doing mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Uploading of document into mapped gcs_bucket/testBucket directory not working.

If you check inside the container using `docker-compose exec storage sh`, you will see that the storage data is in `/storage`, not `/data`.

Therefore, you can add the volume `- ./.storage:/storage` to check for uploaded files.

(Do not set the flag if you specify `-backend memory` at runtime, as you will not be able to see the files.)

> 2. In apiEndpoint, instead of localhost, I need to mention my ipv4 ipaddress starting 192.168.

Try `http://storage:8083`.

Comment: I tried this to see actual file but I am getting below error in console.
`reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.31.0.2:8083`

Comment: @Kammy Do you have the wrong host URL and container name to access?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749385/connect-to-another-container-using-docker-compose

Comment: I tried with `http://storage:8083` host url to create GoogleStorage object. That is service name.

Comment: @Kammy This error is probably due to a connection being refused because the URL in the `-external-url` option does not match the host of the URL that was actually accessed. If you are only using it for testing purposes, try removing the `-external-url` option.