# cannot reach to my localstack S3 from my test container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, localstack

Below is my docker compose yaml file.

```
localstack:
  image: xxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/hub/localstack/localstack:latest
  container_name: localstack
  ports:
    - "4566:4566"
  environment:
    - SERVICES=s3
    - DEBUG=1
    - DATA_DIR=
    - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
    - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
    - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=fake
    - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=fake
    - HOSTNAME=localstack
    - HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL=localstack
  volumes:
    - "${LOCALSTACK_VOLUME_DIR:-./volume}:/var/lib/localstack"
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

test:
  image: xxx.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/build-images/build-image:0.12.0
  container_name: test
  environment:
    - AWS_REGION=us-east-1
    - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=myAccessKeyId
    - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=mySecretAccessKey
    - JAVA_OPTS=-Dwebdriver.chrome.whitelistedIps=
    - ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT_PWD=${ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT_PWD}
    - ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT=${ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT}
  ports:
    - "46050:46050"
  volumes:
    - .:/tmp
  depends_on:
    - db
  entrypoint:
    - tail
    - -f
    - /dev/null
```

When I run the `docker-compose up -d`, both two containers seem boot successfully. However, when I tried to list the S3 buckets on my localstack container from the test  `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 ls`, I got the error below:

```
Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "http://localhost:4566/"
```

Below is the logs printed in localstack container:

```
LocalStack supervisor: starting
LocalStack supervisor: localstack process (PID 15) starting
LocalStack version: 3.0.3.dev
LocalStack Docker container id: f476389c1d5a
LocalStack build date: 2023-12-07
LocalStack build git hash: 40266a13
2023-12-12T05:18:54.655 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore._cache           : reading /root/.cache/python-entrypoints/6ebcf49943e60a3f3e28a4612bb5d19d74cc786b2d2635e6690c6e41d3239d47
2023-12-12T05:18:54.662 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore._cache           : writing to /root/.cache/python-entrypoints/6ebcf49943e60a3f3e28a4612bb5d19d74cc786b2d2635e6690c6e41d3239d47
2023-12-12T05:18:54.664 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='_patch_botocore_json_parser', value='localstack.aws.client:_patch_botocore_json_parser', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.665 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='_publish_config_as_analytics_event', value='localstack.runtime.analytics:_publish_config_as_analytics_event', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.665 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='_publish_container_info', value='localstack.runtime.analytics:_publish_container_info', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.665 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='_run_init_scripts_on_start', value='localstack.runtime.init:_run_init_scripts_on_start', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.667 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='deprecation_warnings', value='localstack.plugins:deprecation_warnings', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.667 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='register_partition_adjusting_proxy_listener', value='localstack.plugins:register_partition_adjusting_proxy_listener', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.667 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='setup_dns_configuration_on_host', value='localstack.dns.plugins:setup_dns_configuration_on_host', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.668 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='start_dns_server', value='localstack.dns.plugins:start_dns_server', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.668 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='validate_configuration', value='localstack.services.lambda_.plugins:validate_configuration', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_start')
2023-12-12T05:18:54.670 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start._patch_botocore_json_parser = <function _patch_botocore_json_parser at 0x7ffffc139f80>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:_patch_botocore_json_parser
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start._publish_config_as_analytics_event = <function _publish_config_as_analytics_event at 0x7ffffc13a340>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:_publish_config_as_analytics_event
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start._publish_container_info = <function _publish_container_info at 0x7ffffc13a660>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:_publish_container_info
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start._run_init_scripts_on_start = <function _run_init_scripts_on_start at 0x7ffffc13b600>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:_run_init_scripts_on_start
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start.deprecation_warnings = <function deprecation_warnings at 0x7ffffc13bd80>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:deprecation_warnings
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start.register_partition_adjusting_proxy_listener = <function register_partition_adjusting_proxy_listener at 0x7ffffc13bc40>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:register_partition_adjusting_proxy_listener is disabled
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start.setup_dns_configuration_on_host = <function setup_dns_configuration_on_host at 0x7ffffc17c0e0>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:setup_dns_configuration_on_host
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start.start_dns_server = <function start_dns_server at 0x7ffffc13bf60>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:start_dns_server
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_start.validate_configuration = <function validate_configuration at 0x7ffffc17f880>)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.671 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_start:validate_configuration
2023-12-12T05:18:54.958 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Determined fallback dns: 127.0.0.11
2023-12-12T05:18:54.958 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Starting DNS servers (tcp/udp port 53 on 0.0.0.0)...
2023-12-12T05:18:54.958 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Adding host .*localhost.localstack.cloud pointing to LocalStack
2023-12-12T05:18:54.958 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Adding host .*localhost.localstack.cloud with record DynamicRecord(record_type=<RecordType.A: 1>, record_id=None)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.958 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Adding host .*localhost.localstack.cloud with record DynamicRecord(record_type=<RecordType.AAAA: 2>, record_id=None)
2023-12-12T05:18:54.962 DEBUG --- [-functhread1] localstack.dns.server      : DNS Server started
2023-12-12T05:18:55.994 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : DNS server startup finished.
2023-12-12T05:18:55.996 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.runtime.init    : Init scripts discovered: {BOOT: [], START: [], READY: [], SHUTDOWN: []}
2023-12-12T05:18:55.996 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.plugins         : Checking for the usage of deprecated community features and configs...
2023-12-12T05:18:55.998  WARN --- [  MainThread] localstack.deprecations    : DATA_DIR is deprecated (since 1.0.0) and will be removed in upcoming releases of LocalStack! Please use PERSISTENCE instead. The state will be stored in your LocalStack volume in the state/ directory.
2023-12-12T05:18:55.998  WARN --- [  MainThread] localstack.deprecations    : HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL is deprecated (since 2.0.0) and will be removed in upcoming releases of LocalStack! This configuration will be migrated to LOCALSTACK_HOST
2023-12-12T05:18:55.998 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.dns.server      : Overwriting container DNS server to point to localhost
2023-12-12T05:18:56.021 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] localstack.utils.threads   : start_thread called without providing a custom name
2023-12-12T05:18:56.022 DEBUG --- [-functhread3] localstack.utils.run       : Executing command: whoami
2023-12-12T05:18:56.183  WARN --- [-functhread3] l.services.internal        : Enabling diagnose endpoint, please be aware that this can expose sensitive information via your network.
2023-12-12T05:18:56.187 DEBUG --- [-functhread3] localstack.utils.ssl       : Attempting to download local SSL certificate file
2023-12-12T05:18:57.280  INFO --- [-functhread3] localstack.utils.http      : Unable to download Github artifact from from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/localstack/localstack-artifacts@master/local-certs/server.key to /var/lib/localstack/cache/server.test.pem: MyHTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn.jsdelivr.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gh/localstack/localstack-artifacts@master/local-certs/server.key (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)'))) Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 468, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1097, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 471, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 515, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1108, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 1379, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 791, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 492, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 845, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: MyHTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn.jsdelivr.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gh/localstack/localstack-artifacts@master/local-certs/server.key (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/http.py", line 264, in do_download
    download(download_url, target_file, timeout=timeout, request_headers=request_headers)
  File "/opt/code/localstack/localstack/utils/http.py", line 198, in download
    r = s.get(url, stream=True, verify=_verify, timeout=timeout, headers=request_headers)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 602, in get
    return self.request("GET", url, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/code/localstack/.venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: MyHTTPSConnectionPool(host='cdn.jsdelivr.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /gh/localstack/localstack-artifacts@master/local-certs/server.key (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)')))
2023-12-12T05:18:57.301  INFO --- [-functhread4] hypercorn.error            : Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)
2023-12-12T05:18:57.301  INFO --- [-functhread4] hypercorn.error            : Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566 (CTRL + C to quit)
2023-12-12T05:18:57.545  INFO --- [  MainThread] localstack.utils.bootstrap : Execution of "start_runtime_components" took 1523.14ms
2023-12-12T05:18:57.545 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='acm:default', value='localstack.services.providers:acm', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.549 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='apigateway:default', value='localstack.services.providers:apigateway', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.549 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='cloudformation:default', value='localstack.services.providers:cloudformation', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.549 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='cloudwatch:default', value='localstack.services.providers:cloudwatch', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.549 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='config:default', value='localstack.services.providers:awsconfig', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.549 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='dynamodb:default', value='localstack.services.providers:dynamodb', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.549 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='dynamodbstreams:default', value='localstack.services.providers:dynamodbstreams', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='ec2:default', value='localstack.services.providers:ec2', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='es:default', value='localstack.services.providers:es', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='events:default', value='localstack.services.providers:events', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='firehose:default', value='localstack.services.providers:firehose', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='iam:default', value='localstack.services.providers:iam', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='kinesis:default', value='localstack.services.providers:kinesis', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='kms:default', value='localstack.services.providers:kms', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='lambda:asf', value='localstack.services.providers:lambda_asf', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='lambda:default', value='localstack.services.providers:lambda_', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='lambda:v2', value='localstack.services.providers:lambda_v2', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='logs:default', value='localstack.services.providers:logs', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='opensearch:default', value='localstack.services.providers:opensearch', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='redshift:default', value='localstack.services.providers:redshift', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='resource-groups:default', value='localstack.services.providers:resource_groups', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='resourcegroupstaggingapi:default', value='localstack.services.providers:resourcegroupstaggingapi', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='route53:default', value='localstack.services.providers:route53', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='route53resolver:default', value='localstack.services.providers:route53resolver', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='s3:asf', value='localstack.services.providers:s3_asf', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='s3:default', value='localstack.services.providers:s3', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='s3:legacy_v2', value='localstack.services.providers:s3_legacy_v2', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='s3:stream', value='localstack.services.providers:s3_stream', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='s3:v2', value='localstack.services.providers:s3_v2', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='s3:v3', value='localstack.services.providers:s3_v3', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='s3control:default', value='localstack.services.providers:s3control', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='scheduler:default', value='localstack.services.providers:scheduler', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='secretsmanager:default', value='localstack.services.providers:secretsmanager', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='ses:default', value='localstack.services.providers:ses', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='sns:default', value='localstack.services.providers:sns', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='sqs-query:default', value='localstack.services.providers:sqs_query', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='sqs:default', value='localstack.services.providers:sqs', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='ssm:default', value='localstack.services.providers:ssm', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='stepfunctions:default', value='localstack.services.providers:stepfunctions', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='stepfunctions:legacy', value='localstack.services.providers:stepfunctions_v1', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='stepfunctions:v1', value='localstack.services.providers:stepfunctions_legacy', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.550 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='stepfunctions:v2', value='localstack.services.providers:stepfunctions_v2', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='sts:default', value='localstack.services.providers:sts', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='support:default', value='localstack.services.providers:support', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='swf:default', value='localstack.services.providers:swf', group='localstack.aws.provider')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='transcribe:default', value='localstack.services.providers:transcribe', group='localstack.aws.provider')
Ready.
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='_run_init_scripts_on_ready', value='localstack.runtime.init:_run_init_scripts_on_ready', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_ready')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] stevedore.extension        : found extension EntryPoint(name='register_virtual_host_routes', value='localstack.services.s3.virtual_host:register_virtual_host_routes', group='localstack.hooks.on_infra_ready')
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_ready._run_init_scripts_on_ready = <function _run_init_scripts_on_ready at 0x7ffffc13b740>)
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_ready:_run_init_scripts_on_ready
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.hooks.on_infra_ready.register_virtual_host_routes = <function register_virtual_host_routes at 0x7ffff885ede0>)
2023-12-12T05:18:57.551 DEBUG --- [  MainThread] plugin.manager             : plugin localstack.hooks.on_infra_ready:register_virtual_host_routes is disabled
2023-12-12T05:19:04.221 DEBUG --- [   asgi_gw_0] l.a.p.service_router       : loading service catalog index cache file /var/lib/localstack/cache/service-catalog-3_0_3_dev-1_32_5.pickle
2023-12-12T05:19:13.884 DEBUG --- [   asgi_gw_0] plugin.manager             : instantiating plugin PluginSpec(localstack.aws.provider.s3:default = <function s3 at 0x7ffff885cfe0>)
2023-12-12T05:19:13.884 DEBUG --- [   asgi_gw_0] plugin.manager             : loading plugin localstack.aws.provider:s3:default
2023-12-12T05:19:14.154  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS s3.CreateBucket => 200
```

Please note that the last line about "createBucket => 200" is that I manually (aws cli) created a bucket within localstack container itself.

Any idea why I cannot reach to the localstack S3? Thanks.

Comment: Surely you meant `aws --endpoint-url=http://localstack:4566 s3 ls` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to another container using Docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749385/connect-to-another-container-using-docker-compose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really get that error, this happens because localstack is *not* available at localhost related to `test` container.

Both of these containers have their own localhost. If you want to connect to the localstack from your other container, the connect endpoint would be: `http://localstack:4566`

Docker containers in the same compose file can by default access each other with the service name as the host name, in this case `localstack` and `test`.