# Express gateway always return Bad Gateway when I run with docker-compose or docker

Tags: node.js, docker, microservices, express-gateway

**Express gateway always return Bad Gateway when I run with docker-compose or docker**
I am trying to build a MERN  stack application  using the NodeJS and microservice architecture and i have completed the project and Dockerized and while I am trying to run the API gateway and the user service it always returns the Bad gateway error

here is my gateway.config.yml

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  host: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/ip'
  user:
    host: localhost
    paths: '/user/*'
  gig: 
    host: localhost
    paths: ['/gig', '/gig/*']
  message: 
    host: localhost
    paths: ['/message', '/message/*']
  order: 
    host: localhost
    paths: ['/order', '/order/*']
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
  userService: 
    url: 'http://user-service:8001'
  gigService: 
    url: 'http://gig-service:8002'
  messageService: 
    url: 'http://message-service:8004'
  orderService: 
    url: 'http://order-service:8003'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: httpbin 
              changeOrigin: true
  userPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - user
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: userService
              changeOrigin: true
  gigPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - gig
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: gigService
              changeOrigin: true
  messagePipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - message
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: messageService
              changeOrigin: true
  orderPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - order
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: orderService
              changeOrigin: true
```

And this is my docker compose file

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  api-service:
    image: aswanth600/api:latest
    container_name: api-container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - my-network  

  user-service:
    image: aswanth600/user:latest
    container_name: user-container
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    networks:
      - my-network  

  order-service:
    image: aswanth600/order:latest
    container_name: order-container
    ports:
      - "8003:8003"
    networks:
      - my-network  

  gig-service:
    image: aswanth600/gig:latest
    container_name: gig-container
    ports:
      - "8002:8002"
    networks:
      - my-network  

  message-service:
    image: aswanth600/message:latest
    container_name: message-container
    ports:
      - "8004:8004"
    networks:
      - my-network  


networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

then my docker file of user service is

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect to another container using Docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35749385/connect-to-another-container-using-docker-compose)

Comment: I don't know which one is your gateway service but I suspect you'll need to change those `localhost` entries to use the compose service name instead

Answer (score -1):

I changed the localhost entries to use the compose service name instead then it worked

gateway.config

```
http:
  port: 8080
admin:
  port: 9876
  host: localhost
apiEndpoints:
  api:
    host: api-service
    paths: '/ip'
  user:
    host: user-service
    paths: '/user/*'
  gig: 
    host: gig-service
    paths: ['/gig', '/gig/*']
  message: 
    host: message-service
    paths: ['/message', '/message/*']
  order: 
    host: order-service
    paths: ['/order', '/order/*']
serviceEndpoints:
  httpbin:
    url: 'https://httpbin.org'
  userService: 
    url: 'http://user-service:8001'
  gigService: 
    url: 'http://gig-service:8002'
  messageService: 
    url: 'http://message-service:8004'
  orderService: 
    url: 'http://order-service:8003'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - log
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit
pipelines:
  default:
    apiEndpoints:
      - api
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: httpbin 
              changeOrigin: true
  userPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - user
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: userService
              changeOrigin: true
  gigPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - gig
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: gigService
              changeOrigin: true
  messagePipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - message
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: messageService
              changeOrigin: true
  orderPipeline:
    apiEndpoints:
      - order
    policies:
    # Uncomment `key-auth:` when instructed to in the Getting Started guide.
    # - key-auth:
      - proxy:
          - action:
              serviceEndpoint: orderService
              changeOrigin: true
```